# Reason for exactly the same symbols in yacc rules?

Tags: yacc

```
identifiers:
    IDENTIFIER
    | identifiers ',' IDENTIFIER
    ;

identifiers_or_typenames:
    identifier
    | identifiers_or_typenames ',' identifier
    ;
```

It seems to me that there's no difference between `identifiers` and `identifiers_or_typenames` since they evaluates to the same stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect there to be code attached to those cases in practice which distinguishes between the two semantically instead of syntactically.  Specifically, the former declaration would dynamically reject `<typename>`s (`yyerror("typename \"%s\" used as identifier", $1);` or similar).

Answer (score 0):

Note that yacc is case-sensitive, so `IDENTIFIER` and `identifier` are two different things that might have no relation to each other, or might be similar but slightly different in some subtle way.  You have to look at how they are defined to tell.  I would guess you might well have a rule of the form

```
identifier: IDENTIFIER | TYPENAME ;
```

which makes your two rules quite different.